# problem injecting Sessionscoped bean in Managed bean

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb

I have a Session scoped bean

```
@SessionScoped
public class UserData implements Serializable {

private String uid;

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(final String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}
```

I'm setting a value in a SessionScoped bean in my stateless session bean

```
public void setOperator(final Operator operator) {
    userData.setUid(operator.getId());
}
```

When I try to get the object with @Inject I only get null

```
@ManagedBean(name = "RoleController")
@SessionScoped
public class RoleController {

...

@Inject
private UserData userData;

...

public UserData getUserData() {
    System.out.println("ID");
    System.out.println(userData.getUid());
```

I have a bean.xml

Comment: Which application server are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
@ManagedBean(name = "RoleController")
```

with

```
@Named("RoleController")
```

and ensure you are importing javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped and not javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped for both of your classes.